# How do I solve the D'Alembert equation: $x(\frac{dy}{dx})=y+\frac{1}{4}(\frac{dy}{dx})^4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^4$$

I know it's the D'Alembert equation. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please carefully review the post [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.4717), and then edit your question accoringly.

Comment: Of course you're right. You added a question to the title. The question is, Is it better? Will it Interest people? .There are many questions in the forum that are not questions in the title. If it's going to unravel when I do it, I'll do it from now on.

Comment: It is better, because any one can ask "integration problem" in a title, but it doesn't inform anyone any more than the tag "integration* already has.  In your case, "D'Alembert equation" tells no one about about your specific question. Yes, please include what you are asking about specifically, particularly, like you see here now, when it *all fits in one line in the title.

Comment: Okay , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=y'$. Then the equation becomes
$$ xp=y+\frac14 p^4. $$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t $p$ gives
$$ \frac{dx}{dp}p+x=\frac{dy}{dp}+p^3. $$
Using
$$ \frac{dy}{dp}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dp}=p\frac{dx}{dp} $$
one has
$$ \frac{dx}{dp}p+x=p\frac{dx}{dp}+p^3 $$
or
$$ x=p^3. $$
So
$$ y'=p=\sqrt[3]{x} $$
and hence
$$ y=\frac{3}{4}x^{\frac{4}{3}}+C. $$